# Thread null-pointer exception Java netbeans

Tags: java, multithreading, syntax, java-threads

I'm trying to open a thread in Java, but for some reason I get an exception every time. my syntax :

```
Thread receiveThread2;
receiveThread2 = new Thread(() -> {
    try {
        receiveMessageNoLoop();
    }
    catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(ModelClient.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
});    
receiveThread2.start();
```

My function `receiveMessageNOLoop()` is in the same Java class:

```
public void receiveMessageNoLoop() throws IOException {
    String stringData;
    inFromServer.read(dataForLoop2, 0, 1024);
    takeCareOfJason(dataForLoop2);
}
```

If I do that without a thread, it works perfectly. problem is, I must use thread and for some reason it gives me nullPointerException.

Comment: You say you get an exception every time.  The answer probably is in the exception stack trace.  The stack trace will tell you exactly which line of your program it was thrown from.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting recieveThread2 to null first.

```
    Thread recievThread2 = null;
```

But I would recommend using the executor service to start your threads

```
    ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
    executorService.execute(() -> {/*Your code*/});
```